# jQuery Mobile pagechange event when replacing only content

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

I'm working on a jquery mobile project with a rails backend.

I have a "master" template, with the page structure as suggested from [jQuery mobile website](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/pages/).
I have a multi-page system and for every page I have the same "master" template (header, footee...) and replace only the html in the `<div data-role="content">`.
So the header and footer are in the "master" template while the content changes for every page.

The problem is that I can't bind to any event because the page id is always the same, only the "content" div changes. This way if I subscribe to the "pagechange" event of the page, it fires for every page and I cannot apply a per-page javascript behaviour.

Do you have any suggestion on how to do this in a clean way?

Thank you,
Riccardo

Comment: You change pages or just change contents? If you have many pages, you need to give each one a unique id

Comment: I just change content. I have many different pages (views) and I replace content, not the whole page

Comment: Can you post your markup and code?

Comment: Just found the problem: my "master" template includes the div with data-role="page". This div has always the same id, so events are fired multiple times when pages are loaded into the DOM. Changing the id of the div for every page, I was able to bind to the events of that page.

Comment: As per my first comment, each page should have a unique id.

Comment: Yes, that's true. That way I can subscribe to events for that page id. The only problem is that jQM doesn't remove the first loaded page from the DOM, so the "pagechange" is never fired for that page (except the first time you visit it).

Comment: if you want to remove the first page `$(document).on('pagehide', '#pageID', function () { $(this).remove(); });`

Comment: Do you think this could have any side effect?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. What you aim for by removing it?

Comment: Well, if I navigate away from the first loaded page (say index.html) and then I come back there, i find that events doesn't fire on that page.

Comment: It's difficult to give you a definite answer without knowing your pages structure and what you want to achieve.